# regex negative lookahead of optional word

Tags: regex

I want to match if the string has `APPLE BANANA` an optional `CARROT` as long as `CARROT` is not followed by `VEGETABLE`

My test strings, first ones should match, last one should not

```
APPLE BANANA CARROT FRUIT
APPLE BANANA VEGETABLE FRUIT
APPLE BANANA NOT FRUIT
APPLE BANANA CARROT 
APPLE BANANA CARROT FRUIT VEGETABLE

APPLE BANANA CARROT VEGETABLE FRUIT
```

I've gotten this which is `CARROT` required:
`APPLE BANANA (CARROT\s+)(?!VEGETABLE)`

https://regex101.com/r/uZQOA7/4

But when I try to make `(CARROT\s+)` optional like `(CARROT\s+)?` it isn't doing what I *thought* it should do.  I'm missing something here.

Comment: If this is for PCRE, you can also use verbs, eg. let match fail on an optional vegetable if we got carrot: [`\bAPPLE BANANA(?: +CARROT\b(?: +VEGETABLE\b(*SKIP)(*F))?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/AeG3o9/1) but it's more playing, not really a nice solution :) Interesting task however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the check in the lookahead, checking that after BANANA there is not CARROT VEGETABLE. If that is the case, then match an optional CARROT.

```
\bAPPLE BANANA(?!\s+CARROT\s+VEGETABLE\b)(?:\s+CARROT\b)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SukOOm/1)

Comment: OHHHH!  Are negative lookaheads zero width assessments?

Comment: @sniperd Yes they are.

Comment: Ha! Every time I think I have regexes figured out, I have to get hit by one of these.  Thank you!